# Is there any way to access iPhone mail app mailboxes inside my own iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I wonder if there's any way to loop inside a mailbox and get the list of messages inside the mailbox.

I want to open each message and take screen shot of the email. Is there any way to do this? Any reference?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is not. The only mail interface comes from the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 6):

I **hope** not.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user for their credentials, and access it via standard POP3/IMAP. If your use is legitimate, they'll be more than happy to enter them. Apple won't permit this sort of behaviour, because they really don't want a fart app stealing some CEO's private e-mail.