# How to get information about e-mails in Mail.app

Tags: iphone, email

If a user is reading e-mails in Mail.app and closes this application and opens my application. I want to show the information about the mail read by the user. Is there some way to get information about the email (in Mail.app), so that I use it in my application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276640/is-there-any-way-to-access-iphone-mail-app-mailboxes-inside-my-own-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of reading the user's email.